# Generating html report of junit xml generated of python unit tests

Tags: jenkins, xslt, junit, jenkins-plugins

I have python unit test report generated by junit in xml fomrat from the jenkins.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuites>
<testsuite name="pytest" errors="0" failures="0" skipped="1" tests="3" time="0.023" timestamp="2021-08-29T21:42:01.852698" hostname="infinity">
<testcase classname="tests.SimpleTest" name="test_fail" time="0.000" />
<testcase classname="tests.SimpleTest" name="test_pass" time="0.000" />
<testcase classname="tests.SimpleTest" name="test_skipped" time="0.000">
<skipped type="pytest.skip" message="demonstrating skipping">
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GithubExample/tests.py:10: demonstrating skipping
</skipped>
</testcase>
</testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Now I want to generate an html report which then I can use Publish HTML report plugin to publish to be accessible from confluence.

Now at my workplace I do not have junit macro and maybe not have other html generation plugin what I have is xsltproc ,

I tried to generated htmlreport using xsltproc but it throws an error

```
xsltproc test-result.xml stylesheet.xslt > index.html
warning: failed to load external entity "test-result.xml"
cannot parse test-result.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [junit2html](https://pypi.org/project/junit2html/). It is easy to use and provides a few options to print tests summary to terminal output or create a summary in the html too.

Even though it is a python module, you can execute it from shell.

Example: `junit2html report.xml report.html`